# Loop through all JSON on page and find specific id

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two JSON on my page, the second contains the specific object 'articleSection' and the first does not. I am attempting to loop through all scripts until JSON is found, then loop through each JSON to determine if 'articleSection exists'. If it does exists, I want to return the value of 'articleSection.

I've gotten this far, but the return is always undefined.

```
function getJSON() {
  var JSONS = document.getElementsByTagName("Script")

  for (i=0; i<JSONS.length;i++){
    if (JSONS[i].getAttribute("type") == "application/ld+json"){
      var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(JSONS[i].innerText);
          if (jsonParsed.articleSection != null && jsonParsed.articleSection != ""){ 
            return jsonParsed.articleSection;
            }
      }
 }
}
```

My thinking is that I am not correctly looping through each of the JSON scripts, but rather only through the first one that is found in the initial `if JSONS[i].getAttribute("type") == "application/ld+json`

JSON For Refrence:

**JSON ONE:**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context" : "http://schema.org",
        "@type" : "Organization",
      }
    </script>
```

**JSON TWO:**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@type": "Article",
          "keywords": "",
          "author": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Staff"
          },
          "articleSection": "Christmas, Festivals, Events, Life, Arts"
}
```

Comment: `have two JSON on my page` is like saying `I have 3 HTML on my page` - it don't make sense.

Comment: Where is your json?

Comment: just added, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

To check `articleSection` in `jsonParsed` you can use `if (jsonParsed.articleSection){`, this will check for `null`, `undefined` and empty string.
The reason your code was not working is JSON was malformed as in the JSON

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "Organization",
  }
</script>
```

you have `,` after `'Organization'`, remove it and it will work.

**LIVE DEMO**

```js
function getJSON() {
  var JSONS = document.querySelectorAll("script[type='application/ld+json']");
  for (var i=0; i<JSONS.length;i++){
      var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(JSONS[i].innerHTML);
      if (jsonParsed.articleSection){ 
        return jsonParsed.articleSection;
      }
   }
}
console.log(getJSON());
```

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization"
  }
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Article",
    "keywords": "",
    "author": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Staff"
    },
    "articleSection": "Christmas, Festivals, Events, Life, Arts"
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided the extra detail. This does indeed work, but it does not appear to work in Google Tag Manager where I have this set up as a variable using this custom Javascript. It is still returning as undefined (and I have insured that the JSON is cleaned to remove the extra comma as well)

Comment: You can use `var JSONS = document.querySelectorAll("script[type='application/ld+json']");` to get script with your given attribute, so this will remove your if condition inside the for loop. Please `console.log()` in Google Tag Manager and see if it fetching any result or not.